# Setting State in Event causing Maximum Call Error

Tags: reactjs

I've got a method which runs off an event call when someone types in an input field, however all I am seeing is 'maximum call stack error',
I've commented out code until I've discovered this method which is causing the issue...

```
changeEvent(event) {
   //console.log( 'Name:', event.target.name );
   //console.log( 'Value:', event.target.value );
   const formDataRaw = { ...this.state.formData };
   const name = event.target.name;
   const value = event.target.value;
   formDataRaw[name] = value;
   this.setState({formData : formDataRaw});
}
```

Specifically it seems to be setting the state causing the problem.

Comment: Could you please include your entire component? It's difficult to tell what is wrong from this function alone.

Comment: Sure, here is the entire component...
http://pastebin.com/MtkchLNz

Answer (score 0):

I think your input field's `value` event is tied to this `formData[name]` method. So, when you set state in `changeEvent`, it changes the input field and that in turn invokes onChange event and hence you are in a never ending loop, resulting  'maximum call stack error'

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about changing that? I've pasted the entire component here.. http://pastebin.com/MtkchLNz